# checkbox style with css and it wont work.c

Tags: html, css

css

```
/* SQUARED THREE */
/* SQUARED THREE */
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);

}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

i have a checkbox with style by this css but once i use this css i cant off click it again. i wanted the checkbox always set checked.how i going to make it on and off with this css ?

what wrong with the css ?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/zxqj7bcb/)

Comment: Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/zxqj7bcb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, he doesn't. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxqj7bcb/2/

Remember, the `for=` in the `<label>` must match the ID on the `<input>`

```css
/* SQUARED THREE */
.squaredThree {
 width: 20px; 
 margin: 20px auto;
 position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 0;
 border-radius: 4px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredThree label:after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 9px;
 height: 5px;
 background: transparent;
 top: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
 border-top: none;
 border-right: none;

 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rememberMe__checkBox squaredThree">
<input type="checkbox" id="loginInput-rememberMe" name="login-rememberme" checked="checked"/>
<label for="loginInput-rememberMe"></label>
<p>Remember me</p>
</div><!-- end rememberme__checkbox -->
```

Comment: thank you , i never think about that part. appreicate.

Comment: That _should_ be an integral part of writing the form. Practice, it will become second nature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your checkbox on top of the label in order to make it work:

```
#loginInput-rememberMe {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxqj7bcb/1/)